# Class.forname("name").newInstance() vs name.class.newInstance : Difference in usage perspective

Tags: java, reflection

I will start with my example:
I have a class `classload.Loadable` .

```
package classload;

public class Loadable {
    static{
        System.out.println("Loaded already.....");
    }
    public Loadable(){
        System.out.println("Now created.....");
    }
}
```

which will be loaded and created instance in the following 2 ways.

**First:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Starting .....");
                Class.forName("classload.Loadable").newInstance();
            }
```

**Second:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Starting .....");

                classload.Loadable.class.newInstance();
            }
```

**Both gives same output as expected(since `Class.forname` returns the same `class` object)**:

```
Starting .....
Loaded already.....
Now created.....
```

I want to know which all scenarios we use `Class.forname` and whereever we may use `.class` object directly

Comment: It would be pretty weird to use `classload.Loadable.class.newInstance()` instead of just `new classload.Loadable()`.

Comment: Agreed.I included that to create this example.Actually in my case I would get a Class<?> as an argument to my method, where the instance creation is taken place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use

```
new Loadable();
```

if the class is know at compile time and you expect it to be available at runtime. Note: this will throw a `NoClassDefError` at runtime if it is not available.

If you are not sure it will be available a runtime, you might use

```
Class.forName("classload.Loadable").newInstance();
```

as it is clearer as to which exceptions will be thrown.

The problem with

```
classload.Loadable.class.newInstance()
```

is that it's not particularly useful in either context.

Note: `Class.newInstance()` has a known issue were it will throw *checked* exceptions which you don't know about. i.e. if the Constructor throws a checked exception it won't be wrapped and the compiler can't tell what will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

`Class.forName().newInstance()` loads class at runtime. It may succeed, or it may fail, depending on whether the desired class is valid or not. Means your instance created at runtime.

`name.class.newInstance()`: `class` is an class literal which evaluate as compile time constant. It can still fail at runtime if the referenced class is not valid and present within the classpath, but it can be used in places where constant expressions are required.

second calling type is equivalent to `Loadable loadable = new Loadable()`

Comment: `name.class` is a [class literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2), not an operator. `Class.forName()` returns a class, not an instance, and `newInstance()` is indeed required if you want an instance.